# how to generate code for angularjs or front end only

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I tried

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster-angular-ui
```

after that it is not running on grunt server.
I don't know how to install `angular-ui` in `jhipster`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update Jul 24, 2018

As [documented](http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#3), either use `jhipster --skip-server` command line option or run client sub-generator with `jhipster client --[options]`.

### Original as of Nov 18, 2016

As [documented](http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#3), either use `yo jhipster --skip-server` command line option or run client sub-generator with `yo jhipster:client`.

Comment: where I get demo of this?

Comment: You mean as a video?

Comment: yeah because I want to know how to create entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you are an advanced user you can use our client and server sub-generators by running `jhipster client --[options]`:

```
jhipster:client --auth=jwt
```